# Passing through middleware is not reaching the last pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, async-await

Just practicing with `ASP.NET CORE` Middleware I have this code below. I reach it with address h**ttp://localhost:5000/location** and it outputs :

```
Buffalo in USA // that's correct, coming from MessageOptions class.
Status Code: 200
```

my expectation was that the flow be like this:
Print the City and Country name because the path has `/location` in it.
Then with `next()` go to print Status Code 200 which also has a `next()` so I was hoping after that it goes to last one and print the `Hello World` too but it does NOT go to last one to print Hello World.
My question is **WHY?**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IOptions<MessageOptions> options)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    // conditional branching in middleware.
    app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("branch"), branch => { branch.UseMiddleware<QueryStringMiddleWare>(); });

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path == "/location")
        {
            MessageOptions opts = options.Value;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"{opts.CityName} in {opts.CountryName}");
            await next();
        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }
    });

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"\n Status Code: {context.Response.StatusCode} \n");
        await next();
    });

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Get && context.Request.Query["custom"] == "true")
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from Inline Middleware \n");
        }

        await next();
    });

    app.UseMiddleware<QueryStringMiddleWare>();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World From Starutp.cs! \n");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last one matches requests like `HTTP GET http://localhost:5000/` and does not match requests like `HTTP GET http://localhost:5000/location`.

Comment: OH I SEE ... OK Thanks.